# Algoritmo repetindo os dados do último append

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz este algirtmo para adicionar IDADE e NOME em um dict Pessoa quando termina preencher os dados e submita ele envia esse dict para a list Pessoas. O problema é, todas as pessoas adicionar tem o mesmo valores que a última, como eu posso fazer o fatimaneto para que isso não ocorra?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Raul, poste seu código por favor.

Comment: Raul Pacheco, O código aqui no StackOverflow deve ser publicado como texto leia o link a seguir para saber o motivo: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Raul, tudo bom?

Na verdade é bem simples de resolver isso.

Na parte do seu script quando você realiza o 'Pessoas.append(Pessoa)' você precisa inserir uma função .copy(). Refiz seu código no meu editor, se tiver alguma diferença peço que desconsidere.

Perceba como incluí o '.copy()' na linha do seu script onde você incluiu a função '.append().

```
pessoas = []
pessoa = {}

while True:
    decisão = str(input('Você deseja adicionar uma pessoa? S/N\nSua resposta: ')).upper()

    if decisão == 'S':
        pessoa['Nome'] = str(input('Qual o nome da pessoa que deseja adicionar? '))
        pessoa['Idade'] = int(input('Qual idade da pessoa que deseja adicionar? '))

        pessoas.append(pessoa.copy())

    else:
        break
print(pessoas)
```

Acontece que se o seu script possui um looping, onde seu programa automaticamente ficará gerando a pergunta e armazenando o nome e a idade, enquanto a resposta for igual a 'S'. Porém sem realizar uma cópia do que vai sendo incluído, você acabará recebendo o mesmo resultado, igual você teve anteriormente.

Tentei resumir o máximo possível, caso continue com esta dúvida, estou à disposição.

Boa sorte Raul.